# Add a new dataframe column which counts the values in certain column less than the date prior to the time

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

EDITED  
I want to add a new column called prev_message_left which counts the no. of messages_left per ID less than the date prior the given time. Basically I want to have a column which says how many times we had left message on call to that customer prior to the current time and date. This is how my data frame looks like

```
date       ID   call_time   message_left  
20191101    1        8:00              0
20191102    2        9:00              1
20191030    1       16:00              1
20191103    2       10:30              1
20191105    2       14:00              0
20191030    1       15:30              0
```

I want to add an additional column called prev_message_left_count

```
date       ID   call_time   message_left  prev_message_left_count
20191101    1        8:00              0                        1
20191102    2        9:00              1                        0
20191030    1       16:00              1                        0
20191103    2       10:30              1                        1
20191105    2       14:00              0                        2
20191030    1       15:30              0                        0
```

My dataframe has 15 columns and 90k rows.
I have various other columns in this dataframe and there are columns like 'No Message Left', 'Responded' for which I will have to compute additional columns called 'Previous_no_message_left' and 'prev_responded' similar to 'prev_message_left'

Comment: Does the 'prev_message_left_count' column only get the number of messages left from the most recent row for an ID?

Comment: 'prev_message_left_count' column gets the cumulative count of all the messages left prior to the that row's date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to get the cumulative sum in the correct order by groups. You can create groups using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['prev_message_left_count']= (df.sort_values(['date','call_time'])
                                  .groupby('ID')['message_left']
                                  .apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=0)
                                                  .cumsum()) )

print(df)


       date  ID call_time  message_left  prev_message_left_count
0  20191101   1      8:00             0                        1
1  20191102   2      9:00             1                        0
2  20191030   1     16:00             1                        0
3  20191103   2     10:30             1                        1
4  20191105   2     14:00             0                        2
5  20191030   1     15:30             0                        0
```

---

sometimes [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) is slow so it may be advisable

```
df['prev_message_left_count']=( df.sort_values(['date','call_time'])
                                  .groupby('ID')
                                  .shift(fill_value=0)
                                  .groupby(df['ID'])['message_left']
                                  .cumsum()
```